# Why does std::memory_order_relaxed permit side-effect reordering?

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, language-lawyer, c++20

While reading the [cppref article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Relaxed_ordering) on relaxed memory ordering introduced in C++11, I've struggled to understand the example provided to illustrate concurrent memory access (re)ordering.

The article provides the following:

> Atomic operations tagged `memory_order_relaxed` are not synchronization operations; they do not impose an order among concurrent memory accesses. They only guarantee atomicity and modification order consistency.
>
> For example, with x and y initially zero,
>
> ```
> // Thread 1:
> r1 = y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); // A
> x.store(r1, std::memory_order_relaxed); // B
> // Thread 2:
> r2 = x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); // C 
> y.store(42, std::memory_order_relaxed); // D
> ```
>
> [...]

The thing that seems nonsensical to me is the following paragraph (with points of interest bolded):

> [...]
>
> is allowed to produce `r1 == r2 == 42` because, although A is *sequenced-before* B within thread 1 and **C is *sequenced-before* D within thread 2**, nothing prevents D from appearing before A in the modification order of y, and B from appearing before C in the modification order of x. The side-effect of D on y could be visible to the load A in thread 1 while the side effect of B on x could be visible to the load C in thread 2. **In particular, this may occur if D is completed before C in thread 2, either due to compiler reordering or at runtime.**

As the article suggests, the only way that the result `r1 == r2 == 42` could happen is if D is reordered before C, with A and B executing sequentially after D. This however, seems to contradict the definition of *sequenced-before*, which per the [C++20 standard](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/releases/tag/n4868), seems to imply that every side-effect of a full-expression/expression-statement must be visible before the next statement<sup>[1]</sup><sup>[2]</sup>.

My question is, why is this reordering permitted to happen? An assignment to any memory address is considered a side-effect<sup>[3]</sup>, and the full-expression in line C `r2 = x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)` does so by assigning the computation value `x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)` to `r2`. While intuitively speaking, lines C and D carry no variable dependencies on each other, and should be able to be freely reordered (unlike lines A and B, where the stored value x depends on the previously assigned value to r1), the wording of the standard and *sequenced-before* seems to suggest otherwise, implying that the evaluation of C and any of its side-effects (such as storing the loaded value to r2) *strongly happens-before* any of D<sup>[4]</sup>. What am I missing here?

---

###### [1]:

Full-expressions ― §6.9.1 P9:

> Every value computation and side effect associated with a full-expression is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with the next full-expression to be evaluated.

###### [2]:

Expression-statement ― §8.3 P1:

> [...]
>
> All side effects from an expression statement are completed before the next statement is executed. An expression statement with the expression missing is called a null statement.
>
> [Note 1: Most statements are expression statements — usually assignments or function calls. A null statement is useful to carry a label just before the } of a compound statement and to supply a null body to an iteration statement such as a while statement (8.6.2). —*end note*]

###### [3]:

Side-effect (relevant section bolded) ― §6.9.1 P7:

> Reading an object designated by a `volatile` glvalue (7.2.1), **modifying an object**, calling a library I/O function, or calling a function that does any of those operations **are all *side effects***, which are changes in the state of the execution environment. ***Evaluation* of an expression (or a subexpression) in general includes both value computations (including determining the identity of an object for glvalue evaluation and fetching a value previously assigned to an object for prvalue evaluation) and initiation of side effects.** When a call to a library I/O function returns or an access through a volatile glvalue is evaluated the side effect is considered complete, even though some external actions implied by the call (such as the I/O itself) or by the `volatile` access may not have completed yet.

###### [4]:

To quote [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Strongly_happens-before):

> Note: informally, if A *strongly happens-before* B, then A appears to be evaluated before B in all contexts.

Comment: "This however, seems to contradict the definition of sequenced-before, which per the C++20 standard, seems to imply that every side-effect of a full-expression/expression-statement must be visible before the next statement" how are side-effects relevant here in anyway?

Comment: Changing value of an atomic is not a side-effect so I don't see why side-effects are even mentioned.

Comment: @ALX23z without the definition of what «atomic object» is, it is unclear that it is not scalar object. Also, you can use `atomic_ref` to make an object «atomic object» https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/atomics.ref.generic#1

Comment: @ALX23z https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.races heavily uses «side effect» when speaking about modifications of atomic objects

Comment: @LanguageLawyer *context matters*. It wouldn't be the first time when meaning of phrase/state was varied depending on context or even straight up inconsistent through out a long text. There was a cppcon talk mentioning some inconsistencies in the C++ standart regarding usage of words valid/invalid.

Comment: FWIW cppreference took the example and explanation from https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/atomics.order#10

Comment: @Cubbi [atomics.order/9.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/atomics.order#9.2) -- "if an evaluation A is included in the sequence, then every evaluation that assigns to the same variable and happens before A is included."_ -- which you linked to seems to disallow the reordering of statements A and B... which is helpful, but doesn't explain why C and D are _allowed_ to be reordered. Perhaps my understanding of sequenced-before is wrong in believing that it is a guarantee of sequential execution in the same thread?

Comment: @ALX23z Perhaps I wasn't clear, when referring to side-effects here, I specifically refer to the assignment to scalar objects r1 and r2, which is considered a "side-effect" under the referenced [§6.9.1 P7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.exec#intro.execution-7).

Comment: Okey, I think you are forgetting the as-if rule. The compiler can reorder a bunch of stuff if legally it produces the same results. Specifically, relaxed memory operations can be reordered per memory model. For instance, `x.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed); y.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed); x fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed); y.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);` can be simplified into two `fetch_sub(2, ...)`.